# Restrict relay with postfix to certain domain from single IP

Tags: debian, postfix

In my company we're using Postfix as a relay for Google Apps SMTP server in a Debian server. Legacy machines like scanners forward messages to our relay server.

How can i allow the scanner to only send mails through the relay only to certain domains (e.g. our .com)?

I'm pretty sure there's something [here](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html) but I haven't found something working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [postfwd](https://postfwd.org/doc.html) to restrict the domains a specific IP address can send email to (regardless of relay):

```
action=REJECT; client_address=192.168.1.9; recipient_domain!~/dom1\.com|dom2\.com/
```

Easy installation on Ubutu server is as follows:

```
$ apt install postfwd
$ vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
  smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10040
$ vi /etc/postfix/postfwd.cf
  action=REJECT; client_address=192.168.1.9; recipient_domain!~/dom1\.com|dom2\.com/
$ systemctl restart postfwd postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i allow the scanner to *only* send mails through the relay ...

Check this --> [How to set up an SMTP Relay Server](https://serverfault.com/q/776150/208240)

> ... only to certain domains

Check this --> [Is it possible to limit outgoing emails in Postfix to one specific domain?](https://serverfault.com/q/355972/208240)

Comment: I need to combine the two suggestions but at the same time allow other machines to relay to everyone. Something like:

if (sender==scanner) allow relay only to ourdomain.com
else allow relay to everyone